# OpenAI API: How do I get a list of all available OpenAI models?

Tags: openai-api

Can anyone find the cURL command to get a list of all available OpenAI models? I've been looking for like 10 minutes and can't find it.

---

EDIT: I got the answer, and I see the problem. It is one of those docs where everything is on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Python

```
from openai import OpenAI
import os

client = OpenAI(
    api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
)
    
models = client.models.list()

print(models)
```

#### Node.js

```
const OpenAI = require("openai");

const client = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

async function main() {
  const list = await client.models.list();

  for await (const model of list) {
    console.log(model);
  }
}

main();
```

#### cURL

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/models \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY"
```

See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models/list).